# How can I establish a secure end-to-end connection with python

Tags: python, security, connection, end-to-end

I would like to establish a secure NSA proof connection between two peers with perfect forward secrecy and everything else one would expect.

What is the best way to do this in python so that its standards compliment and I could easily communicate with a peer reimplemented in a different language.

It can be assumed the peers know each others ip/port before hand and also know of each others secp256k1 ECDSA public key that can be used to authenticate once the connection is established.

Just to be clear, I need both sides of the connection. The code for the peer awaiting the connection and for the peer initiating the connection.

Comment: I think your question is less related to Python than it is to Security in itself. Consider posting this question on http://security.stackexchange.com/. Your question boils down to encryption in any shape or form, and TLS + standard socket is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer this as technically correct as possible, but my terminology and memory of all the encryption letter-combinations is vague even tho I've studied them for years (lack of long term memory causes this hehe).

To begin with this is a multi-part problem and not really specific to Python. Hence my comment above.

### You have the data link itself, what's the best way to communicate over?

Well a socket is the most fundamental way to do it.
These days you have websockets, sockets and all kinds of high-level communication tools, but they all rely on a basic socket (most likely over IP+TCP packets).

So I'd reccomend you to stick to sockets, unless you know the peers you're talking with uses something specific, then stick to that.

### How to secure the data link

In most cases, you want to stay as legacy as possible without lowering your security. This means you'll probably have to stick to TLS *(Do.. not.. I repeat, do NOT use SSLv*. Unless you know why you need to, do not!)*

Python (and other languages) have nice wrappers for this.
One example how to do it would be:

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

This wraps your plain unprotected socket in a `TLSv1` enclosure between you and a HTTPS enabled web-server. This is one of the most common and secure ways to protect your data-layer.

### Fine tuning the secure data link

In Python, the way to add additional security to the socket is to pass a specific [cipher](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_LIST_FORMAT) combination to the wrapper. like so:

```
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, ..., ciphers=None)
```

For instance, `... ciphers=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)` if you only want to allow `RSA AES 256` and `RSA AES 127 CBC SHA` in your communication. All other ciphers will be discarded and the connection will break.

WHen defining ciphers you're immediately narrowing down your options to communicate.
A lot of software still uses legacy ciphers and some of the software is so out of date that they havn't even updated to `TLSv1` yet and there for is not even aware that some ciphers exist.

**Conclusion**: This all boils down to what you want to communicate with and what software they use.

### Regarding NSA

To be honest, there's no real way of knowing what they can and can't break/decipher.
If you want to be 100% safe, either you're a mathematical genius and you invent your own algorithm/cipher that you're sure that they don't know about.. yet.. And you constantly change it to stay one step ahead.

Or you stick to the most likely secure (and complex) algorithm there is.
I'd google [one time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) if I were you and try to implement something along those lines. It's your best bet of staying out of the standard filter techniques used by infiltrators (NSA counts as one).

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear, I need both sides (the peer awaiting the connection as well).

This is for a peer to peer client where I control both sides, so the ciphers can be more strict.

Comment: @fabe Good, then my answer still stands. One additional note tho, we're not a coding service. So we won't do the programming for you. Show us some effort in trying to solve the problem (perhaps using the above guidelines) and we could help you with a actual implementation problem. As of now you're asking us to code a client and server for you, which we don't typically do (well described in the FAQ).

Comment: Thats ok I'm not asking you to code anything, just what know what the best libs/protocols would be. I just want to establish a canonical example for such a common problem, since I couldn't find a simple obvious answer. Will post the code myself once I get it working, so it can be reviewed since security is of top priority.

Comment: @fabe Again, my answer still stands. It depends on what you're trying to carry over this secure line. real-time-video or text-encryption for instance? Pyt yes, in Python the best way would be a socket + wrapping TLS around it. It's built in, standard protocol and procedure in Python and it can deliver all the content you need. Otherwise i'd look in to tunnels, IPsec specifically since it's the de facto standard in IPv6. That's what I'd use to secure my basic needs.

Comment: @fabe and again, probably more of a security-forum question than straight up programming then. Hence my initial vote to close this question even tho the area speaks dearly to me and i love programming. In this case you're doing a case study on the best approach and not programming in itself. You're looking for method, ciphers and best practices, not code atm. All the libraries needed to solve the case study is supplied in Python by default and I wouldn't dare using anything other than the default for security reasons (Twisted for instance, would never use it when sockets got everything needed)